# Text/plain to json

Tags: javascript, json, aws-lambda

I'm receiving the following variable with a type of text/plain  with newline characters (\r\n) in my js lambda, But I need to convert it to a json with JS

input

```
{"body": "TokenId=dsbfjj&s=b+j%f-b*sfwe1we\r\nTaskid=\r\valueP=12345\r\nvalueN=89542fgdfgdf\r\n"}
```

output:

```
{
   "body":{
      "TokenId":"sbfjj&s=b+j%f-b*sfwe1we",
      "Taskid":"",
      "valueP":"12345",
      "valueN":"89542fgdfgdf"
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, similar like this: {
   "body":{
      "TokenId":"sbfjj&s=b+j%f-b*sfwe1we",
      "Taskid":"",
      "valueP":"12345",
      "valueN":"89542fgdfgdf"
   }
}

Comment: Tangential, but this looks more like correcting a symptom than a problem.

Comment: You want to format it or convert it to a JavaScript object?

Comment: Your input is highly malformed. First of all, why is whatever's coming after `Taskid` `\r\\\` instead of `\r\n`? Besides that, there's a trailing `\r\n`. Are you sure that's exactly how your input is or was that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a typo in your input, simply split the string, split the string again, and you have your result:

```js
const response = {"body": "TokenId=dsbfjj&s=b+j%f-b*sfwe1we\r\nTaskid=\r\nvalueP=12345\r\nvalueN=89542fgdfgdf\r\n"};

const result = {body: {}};

// split the response with "\r\n" then loop over
response.body.split("\r\n").forEach(i => {
  const [key, ...rest] = i.split("=");
  if(key.length) // due to malformed input
    result.body[key] = rest.join("=");
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your split logic is busted.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl what part?

Comment: The value of `TokenId`

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to parse the JSON and figure out how to scope your data. The root keys appears to be "body". Now, you can access that inner string and split on `\r\n`. Now convert those rows (entries, key-value pairs, etc...) to an object.

```js
const splitOnFirst = (str, delim) =>
  (index => [str.slice(0, index), str.slice(index + 1)])
  (str.indexOf(delim));

const parseComplexJsonStr = (nestedJsonStr) => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(nestedJsonStr), [root] = Object.keys(obj);
  return {
    [root]: Object.fromEntries(
      obj[root].trim().split('\r\n').map(row => splitOnFirst(row, '='))
    )
  };
};

const str = '{"body": "TokenId=dsbfjj&s=b+j%f-b*sfwe1we\\r\\nTaskid=\\r\\nvalueP=12345\\r\\nvalueN=89542fgdfgdf\\r\\n"}';

const parsed = parseComplexJsonStr(str);

console.log(parsed);
```

#### Output

```json
{
  "body": {
    "TokenId": "dsbfjj&s=b+j%f-b*sfwe1we",
    "Taskid": "",
    "valueP": "12345",
    "valueN": "89542fgdfgdf"
  }
}
```